# How can I make a typing carousel inside an input placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, placeholder

I want my input placeholder to have a typing carousel, something like [this](https://codepen.io/gschier/pen/jkivt)

I want that [dynamic writing](https://codepen.io/gschier/pen/jkivt) to on my `#myInput` placeholder

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <center><label class="heypal-label"><span id="heypal">HeyPal<span class="gray-lighter">.me/</span></span></label>
        <input id="myInput" type="text" class="form-control conference-input">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-autosize">Go!</button></center>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Any ideas on how to have this done? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really only need to make a new `TxtRotate` object with your input element and text.

```
new TxtRotate(element, textArray, waitTimeMs);
```

Then, to get text in a placeholder, just set the placeholder text on the element.

```
this.el.placeholder = this.txt;
```

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.placeholder = this.txt;

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  new TxtRotate(document.getElementById('myInput'), ["PariMaria", "GentianAnnas", "LinneaSteliana", "UlisesCristobal", "SimonidesLonny"], 2000);
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <center><label class="heypal-label"><span id="heypal">HeyPal<span class="gray-lighter">.me/</span></span></label>
      <input id="myInput" type="text" class="form-control conference-input">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-autosize">Go!</button></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but in the snippet the typing carousel isn't in the placeholder

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize what you wanted. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The example you link to uses CSS styling to mimic the typing caret, so you can't do that exactly, but otherwise you can use exactly the same javascript except that instead of modifying the inner html of a span, you're modifying the `placeholder` attribute of your input.

```
let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.placeholder = 'my text';
```

Obviously, the above sets the placeholder statically, but there's no reason you can't use the same `setTimeout` tick strategy that the provided example uses to rotate the placeholder text.

As for the caret, I'd just use the 'pipe' symbol: `|`. It's not perfect, but it's close enough IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
      this.toRotate = toRotate;
      this.el = el;
      this.loopNum = 0;
      this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
      this.txt = '';
      this.tick();
      this.isDeleting = false;
    };

    TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {

      var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
      var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

      if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
      } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
      }

      this.el.value =this.txt;

      var that = this;
      var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

      if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

      if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = true;
      } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        that.tick();
      }, delta);
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('myInput');
        var toRotate = element.getAttribute('data-rotate');
        var period = element.getAttribute('data-period');
         new TxtRotate(element, JSON.parse(toRotate), period);

      }


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <center><label class="heypal-label"><span id="heypal">HeyPal<span class="gray-lighter">.me/</span></span></label>
        <input id="myInput" type="text" class="form-control conference-input"

     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-autosize">Go!</button></center>
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the TxtRotate, modify the placeholder property of the input and add the caret effect to the text.

```
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
   this.toRotate = toRotate;
   this.el = el;
   this.loopNum = 0;
   this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
   this.txt = '';
   this.tick();
   this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

if (this.isDeleting) {
   this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
} else {
   this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
}

this.el.placeholder = this.txt + '|';

var that = this;
var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
   delta = this.period;
   this.isDeleting = true;
} else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
   this.isDeleting = false;
   this.loopNum++;
   delta = 500;
}

setTimeout(function() {
   that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
   new TxtRotate(document.getElementById('myInput'), [ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ], 2000);
};
```